# How can we handle the `SELECT` statement if we don't know the column_names VB.net?

Tags: vb.net

How can we handle the `SELECT` statement if we don't know the column_names

with my little experience if i have the following query

```
 SELECT * FROM emp
```

i would do

```
    While sqlReader.Read()
        Dim name as string = sqlReader.Item("emp_name")
    End While
```

**Question**

but what if i don't know the number and columns names of what i'm getting 
*is there is any method of handling this* 
a method that tell us that there is x number of columns selected and their names

and then return this as a list of string , i don't know if this is important or not but i'm doing this as a web service

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `FieldCount` property of `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader` to get the number of fields. You can then use the `GetName` property to get the field names.

```
Dim Names as New list(of String) 
For i as integer = 0 to sqlReader.FieldCount -1 
    Names.Add(sqlReader.GetName(i))
Next
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.aspx

Answer (score 2):

The [SqlDataReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) class has the [FieldCount](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.fieldcount%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) property to tell you how many columns there are, and the [GetName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getname%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) method to tell you their names.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Sql Server, you can query the sys.columns view.

```
SELECT name FROM sys.columns WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('tablename');
```

tablename would be 'emp' in your example.

If you are using a different database, you might try the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS view, which returns similar information.

Comment: ... I've used this method many times - Makes the most sense to me if you're looking to, for example, populate a combobox with column names.